# How to show original size of the image without it being stretched in Android?

Tags: android, xml, imageview, fullscreen

Sorry for the my English, Actually the problem is that i get the images through json in android but when i show it in full size the image got stretched can you please tell me what to do??

**this is my xml file**

```
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/portFullImage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="115dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />
```

Comment: Try add android:scaleType="center" in the code.

Comment: you should search before posting question. it is very basic thing I guess. Read [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Comment: no it make my image too small. This is my full size image [link](http://truzzinfotech.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/kigs.jpg)

Comment: Then try android:scaleType="fitXY".

Comment: android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try with `scaleType` in your ImageView

```
<ImageView
 android:scaleType="center"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/logo" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have specified `top` and `bottom` margins by using `android:layout_marginTop="70dp"` and  `android:layout_marginBottom="115dp"` which are very **big amount of space** if device is small in my opinion. it will make your `ImageView` already small.

If you don't bother about it, try **`android:scaleType="centerInside"`** and see if it helps. You may try other scaletypes mentioned in below reference document and check the results.

**Reference:** 
[Various ScaleType of ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)  , [ScaleType](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1846580&seqNum=2)